# Emacs next-error (C-x `) visualization

Tags: emacs, visualization, behavior, emacs23, compiler-errors

when I get a compiler error (in my case gcc) in Emacs (version 23 for information) I use next-error Lisp function to jump to the next error :)

But when I do this the window is split vertically, but I want this to be done horizontally.

Anyone know how to modify this behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081577/setting-emacs-split-to-horizontal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this question: [Setting Emacs Split to Horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081577/setting-emacs-split-to-horizontal)