# compile buffer to show in a vertical buffer

Tags: emacs

emacs 23.2

I have just installed emacs on a 10.1" screen netbook.

However, when I compile my source code the compilation window always opens in a horizontal buffer below my source code buffer.

At work I use a 15" screen and the compilation opens up in a vertical window, which is what I like.

However, on my 10.1", is there any way to force it to open in a vertical window. Its just easier to scroll down and find errors when you have the source code buffer vertical to the compilation buffer.

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these settings:

```
(setq split-height-threshold nil)
(setq split-width-threshold 0)
```

With respect to needing to scroll down the source code, you should check out <kbd>C-x `</kbd> or <kbd>M-x next-error</kbd> and let Emacs do the scrolling for you.

Comment: Thanks, I do use the next-error. One advantage I find is that having the buffers display vertically is that the errors and lines of code are in parallel with each other.

Answer (score 11):

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081577/setting-emacs-split-to-horizontal).

```
(defadvice compile (around split-horizontally activate)
  (let ((split-width-threshold 0)
        (split-height-threshold nil))
    ad-do-it))
```

If you always want to split horizontally when a new buffer is displayed, you can just set the two variables above and dispense with the advice.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the section "[Choosing a window to display](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Choosing-Window.html)" in the Emacs manual. In particular,

> Option `split-width-threshold`
>
> This variable specifies whether `split-window-sensibly` may split windows horizontally. If it is an integer, `split-window-sensibly` tries to horizontally split a window only if it has at least this many columns. If it is `nil`, `split-window-sensibly` will not split the window horizontally. (It still might split the window vertically, though, see above.)