# When opening 2 files in emacs, how can I have them appear side-by-side?

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

Sometimes I launch emacs from the command line with 2 files, as follows:

```
emacs foo.txt bar.txt
```

This opens the emacs window, split vertically:

```
foo.txt
-------
bar.txt
```

How can I edit my .emacs file so that they show up side-by-side, like this?:

```
        |
foo.txt | bar.txt
        |
```

**EDIT**: To clarify, I know how to make this happen *after* emacs has launched (M-x 0, M-x 3, then re-visit bar.txt in the right window). I just want emacs to split side-by-side by default when I launch it, so I don't have to.

Comment: I just asked a very similar question and got an answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683039/opening-more-than-one-file-split-vertically-through-emacs-nw
Enjoy.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a function that will change a pair of vertical windows to a pair of horizontal windows:

```
(defun 2-windows-vertical-to-horizontal ()
  (let ((buffers (mapcar 'window-buffer (window-list))))
    (when (= 2 (length buffers))
      (delete-other-windows)
      (set-window-buffer (split-window-horizontally) (cadr buffers)))))
```

To do this automatically on startup, add this function to `emacs-startup-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook '2-windows-vertical-to-horizontal)
```

Comment: I originally chose one @huitseeker's answer for its simplicity, but it had one drawback. When emacs temporarily splits a window to show, for example, possible filename tab-completions, it would split the current window side-by-side. This is pretty horrible when the current window is only 80 chars long. Sean's answer splits windows side-by-side when you open multiple files on emacs launch, but otherwise lets emacs retain its usual behavior of opening temporary buffers by splitting the current window vertically.

Comment: a small comment like `"Transform vertical split to horizontal split."` to avoid warning of a given lisp checker could be nice.

Answer (score 17):

The following (to add to your .emacs) makes the window splitting default result in side-by-side buffers (rather than one above the other):

```
(setq split-height-threshold nil) 
(setq split-width-threshold 0)
```

This default will also apply when you run a command such as `find-file-other-window` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>).

(On the other hand, to manually split your window to get two side-by-side buffers, consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697514/when-opening-2-files-in-emacs-how-can-i-have-them-appear-side-by-side/6697545#6697545) answer).

Comment: Six years old answer but it worked for me on Emacs 25.1.1.

Comment: This doesn't always work, depending on the current state of split-window-sensibly, inline documentation says ".. prefer either vertical or horizontal splitting"

Answer (score 6):

This has worked well for me. Use the -f function-name from the command-line to have it set up your emacs split-screen workspace as you like. This gives me a 2 x 2 grid of my financial files that I update every day and sets the cursor on the appropriate window at the end. I save this to .bashrc as an alias so I can pull it up with one command (doc_financial).

```
alias doc_financial='emacs -nw financial_accounts.txt -f split-window-horizontally financial_budget.txt -f split-window-vertically financial_taxes.txt -f other-window -f split-window-vertically financial_tasks.txt -f other-window -f other-window -f other-window'
```

Comment: This works perfectly and should’ve been the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Now I just need to get rid of the scratch buffer window which opens on the bottom half.

Answer (score 5):

Use `M-x split-window-horizontally` or `Ctrl-x 3`.

Comment: I know how to do it manually once emacs has launched; I just want emacs to use side-by-side splitting by default when opening multiple files. Editing question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
;; 15-Oct-20  open first file in left window
(defun my-startup-layout ()
  (let ((buffers (mapcar 'window-buffer (window-list))))
    (when (= 2 (length buffers))
      (delete-other-windows)
      (set-window-buffer (split-window-horizontally) (cadr buffers))))
)

(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'my-startup-layout)
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'next-multiframe-window)
;; end of customization to open first file on left
;;
```

Comment: needs detail or clarity

Answer (score -1):

Use split-window-horizontally.

Answer (score -1):

**Ctrl -x 2**
Split window, above and below

Buffer 1 (above) 
Buffer 2 (Below)

**Ctrl -x 3**
Split window, Side by Side

Buffer 1(left) | Buffer 2 (right)

**C-M-v** 
Scroll other window