# How to change the default split-screen direction?

Tags: emacs, split

Emacs usualy automaticaly splits the window horizontaly.

How can I change this default behaviour, so that the window is splited verticaly by default?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but you can hit `C-x 2` to split a window vertically, and `C-x 3` to split a window horizontally.

Comment: Some functions do automatically split the screen. As examples of such, there is magit, slime and rinari

Comment: This will be helpful too. It doesn't change the default behavior, but it helps to toggle from horizontal to vertical and vice-versa. http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ToggleWindowSplit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Emacs Split to Horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081577/setting-emacs-split-to-horizontal)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
M-x Customize-Group [RET] Windows
```

There you have `Split Window Preferred Function`, `Split Height Threshold` and `Split Width Threshold`. Set `Split Height Threshold` to `nil` and `Split Width Threshold` to `0`

Comment: Btw, on saving via Customize I get an error: `split-width-threshold` in emacs 24.4.1.

Comment: @KostiantynRybnikov Sorry, could not reproduce that in 24.4.1. It still works for me.

Comment: Awesome, just had this problem with magit opening a new window below instead of on the right. Simply increased `split-height-threshold` from its default 80 to 200. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 25):

Use   `(setq split-width-threshold nil)` for vertical split.
Use   `(setq split-width-threshold 1 )`  for horizontal split.

Use http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ToggleWindowSplit to toggle between them.
Use http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TransposeWindows to transponse them.

Comment: Isn't it the opposite? (````(setq split-width-threshold 1)```` for vertical split)

Comment: @ghilesZ I had the same reaction, but it can be understood both ways : splitting "horizontally" or "vertically" is always misleading. If you draw a vertical line, the split is horizontal (one part on the left, the other on the right). But one could also say drawing a vertical line does a vertical split. No idea how to settle this ;-)
As for the configuration directive, `(setq split-width-threshold 1 )` draws a vertical line.

Answer (score 11):

For me it worked with

```
(setq split-width-threshold 0)
(setq split-height-threshold nil)
```