# Emacs ediff mode

Tags: emacs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ediff-split-window-function horizontal==vertical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705149/ediff-split-window-function-horizontal-vertical)

Using GNU Emacs 23.4.1. With `M-x ediff-files`

1-How to make the 2 files vertically beside each other. By default they are one top, one down. I want one left and one right.

2-How to scroll automatically to next difference?

Answer (score 3):

To split the panes side-by-side:

```
(setq ediff-split-window-function 'split-window-horizontally
      ediff-window-setup-function 'ediff-setup-windows-plain)
```

(You can explore ediff's settings using <kbd>M-x customize-group RET ediff RET</kbd>.)

<kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd> will take you to the next or previous diff chunk, respectively. Press <kbd>?</kbd> to get the full menu, which includes handy keys to copy changes from buffer 1 to buffer 2 and vice versa.